# Drawing an array of nodes using the foreach-construct

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I sometimes need to visualize an array-like structure with tikz. I use nodes for array elements and position the next node `right of` the previous one, i.e., like this:

```
 \node[draw,rectangle] (n0) {element 1};
 \node[draw,rectangle] (n1) [right of=n0] {element 2};
 \node[draw,rectangle] (n2) [right of=n1] {element 3};
 % many more nodes
```

In other words: I always position the next node `right of` the previous node. I want to simplify that code, e.g., by using a loop, and ideally would like to have something like this:

```
\foreach \id in {1,...,9}
        \draw let \p0 = {\id-1} in node[draw,rectangle] (n\id) {element \id};
```

There is two issues with this:

- The clause `{\id-1}` is not "evaluated", but taken as a string, i.e., "1-1", "2-1", etc. How could I do that? Or, if that is not possible or convenient, can I somehow specify `right of = latest defined id`?
- The first element is special in the sense that it is not relative to any other node. Special cases are always tedious, so I'm wondering if there is a way to define `right of = none`? It'd be nice to draw all nodes with the loop and not having to treat the first element as a special case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another version of `evaluate` uses `remember`.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw, rectangle] (n0) {0};
\foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0)] in {1,...,4}{
    \node [draw, rectangle, right =of n\lastx] (n\x) {\x};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or also (and shorter), using e-TeX's `\numexpr` as in `\coordinate (n0); \foreach \id in {1,...,9} { \node[draw,rectangle,right=of n\the\numexpr\id-1\relax] (n\id) {\id}; }`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Cool. :) I still need to learn all of those things. But I don't know where everybody learns them from. Like `\the`, `\numexpr`, are they in the Tex Book?

Comment: `\the` is a TeX primitive, so it's on *The TeXbook*. `\numexpr` is from e-TeX, so it's not in the *The TeXbook*, but on `etex` documentation.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for the advice. I'll check it out. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is what chains library is for and it automatically names the nodes of your preference. Also you can automatically join them, change directions etc.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain=my chain]
\foreach \i in {0,...,6}{\node [on chain] {element \i};}
\end{scope}
\draw[->] (my chain-2) to[bend left] (my chain-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can have an anchor `\coordinate` with id `0`. Then, there are at least three similar ways to do what you want.

1. Maintain the name of the last node yourself.

   ```
   \coordinate (n0);
   \xdef\mylastnode{0}
   \foreach \id in {1,...,9} {
     \node[draw,rectangle,right=of n\mylastnode] (n\id) {\id};
     \xdef\mylastnode{\id}
   }
   ```

   This is more flexible than just compute `i - 1`.
2. In simple cases such as this (numbered nodes), do the numbers:

   ```
   \coordinate (n0);
   \foreach \id in {1,...,9} {
     \pgfmathparse{\id-1}
     \node[draw,rectangle,right=of n\pgfmathresult] (n\id) {\id};
   }
   ```
3. You can also let `foreach` do the computation.

   ```
   \coordinate (n0);
   \foreach \id [evaluate=\id as \last using \id-1] in {1,...,9} {
     \node[draw,rectangle,right=of n\last] (n\id) {\id};
   }
   ```

Comment: Or also (and shorter), using e-TeX `\numexpr` as in `\coordinate (n0);
\foreach \id  in {1,...,9} {
  \node[draw,rectangle,right=of n\the\numexpr\id-1\relax] (n\id) {\id};
}`